# Google BigQuery max() return wrong result

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

In standard SQL dialect I ran the following query to return to a max, however, the result returns is wrong (see screenshot below). Explanation?

```
SELECT
  oi.customer_ead_to,
  MAX(oi.customer_ead_to) OVER (PARTITION BY oi.order_id) max_customer_ead_to
FROM `rawData.order` o,
UNNEST (items) oi
WHERE oi.order_id = 3689393
```

[Screenshot: The query returns a wrong Max of 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5blsw.png)

Comment: I cannot repro this - can you share job id and project id for this query

Comment: ProjectId: lesara-dwh. JobId: lesara-dwh:bquijob_50ed7990_15bfd3aab22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what most likely happens. `customer_ead_to` is not defined as numeric type (`FLOAT` or `INTEGER`), but rather as `STRING`. Strings have alphabetical comparison rules, and `"15" < "5"`, this is why "5" comes as maximum. You can change your query to cast to integer type as

```
SELECT
  oi.customer_ead_to,
  MAX(CAST(oi.customer_ead_to AS INT64))
    OVER (PARTITION BY oi.order_id) max_customer_ead_to
FROM `rawData.order` o,
UNNEST (items) oi
WHERE oi.order_id = 3689393
```